# How many lines are covered by the Rust conditional compilation attribute?

Tags: rust, conditional-compilation

I'm trying to use a conditional compilation statement. Beyond defining a function that should only exist in a debug build, I want to define a set of variables/constants/types that only exist in the debug build.

```
#[cfg(debug)]
pub type A = B;
pub type B = W;

#[cfg(other_option)]
pub type A = Z;
pub type B = I;
let test = 23i32;
```

How many lines are actually "covered" by the conditional compile attribute in this case? Is it only one (what I would expect in this context)? Are there ways to ensure that a whole block of code (including variables, types and two functions) is covered by the condition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An `#[attribute]` only applies to the next [item](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#items). Please see the [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/attributes.html).

**Edit**: I don't think it is currently possible to spread an attribute over an arbitrary number of declarations.

Additional, in-depth information on attributes and their application can be found at [Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#attributes).

Comment: Thanks! I searched the Rust book but only looked around the explanations for the conditional compile. Thanks for pointing me to the right place!

Comment: The 2nd part of my questions still stays: Is there any way to tell the compiler that such an attribute should cover more than one declaration?

Comment: @DerNils Just a quick tip about StackOverflow: please only ask one question per question-post. In this case it's kind of OK, since the questions are very closely linked. So just for your SO future: make sure to ask just one question; otherwise you risk downvotes. In that sense: welcome to SO :)

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt thanks for the hint and the warm welcome! I hope that my first question will not directly lead to a downvote :-)

Comment: @ljedrz Thanks for extending your answer regarding the 2nd aspect!

Comment: In more recent versions of Rust, it looks like you can use curly braces to cover multiple lines, for example: `#[cfg(feature="blah")] { /* your code */ }`

Just watch the scope.

Answer (score 22):

You can use a module to group together everything that should exist for debug/release only, like this:

```
#[cfg(debug)]
mod example {
    pub type A = i32;
    pub type B = i64;
}

#[cfg(not(debug))]
mod example {
    pub type A = u32;
    pub type B = u64;
}

fn main() {
    let x: example::A = example::A::max_value();
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fd325d59732ed6a70445865900714aea&version=stable&backtrace=0) (note that this will always print the `not(debug)` value because the playground doesn't define the `debug` feature, even in debug mode).

If `debug` is defined, this will print `2147483647` (the maximum value of an `i32`), otherwise it will print `4294967295` (the maximum value of a `u32`). Keep in mind that both modules must have definitions for each item, otherwise you'll hit a compile-time error.

If you've not read about [Attributes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/attributes.html), it might be a good idea to do so; make sure you know the difference between inner attributes (`#![attribute]`) and outer attributes (`#[attribute]`).

Comment: I did indeed consider to wrap my declarations with a module but finally decided against it. For me, a module is a way to structure my code and I don't want to Have a structure preset by the use of a conditional compile. I have to admit though, that I would  solution if would have to do really a large amount of declarations (currently I only have to do 4)

Comment: With only 4 declarations, it's probably manageable at the moment, although there's no real overhead from using a module and probably saves a few lines, especially if you need to scale it up in future. Is there any particular reason you're against using a module, or is it just too bulky for your needs?