# What is the proper way to use the `cfg!` macro to choose between multiple implementations?

Tags: rust

I have specified a few features inside `Cargo.toml`:

```
[features]
complex = []
simple = []
```

When I build my project I use `cargo build --features="complex"` or `simple`.

In some functions, I want to return a value based on which feature is used:

```
fn test() -> u32 {
    let x: u32 = 3;
    if cfg!(feature = "complex") {
        let y: u32 = 2;
        x + y
    }
    if cfg!(feature = "simple") {
        let y: u32 = 1;
        x + y
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work as it tries to evaluate both expressions. What is the proper way to use the `cfg!` macro in my case?

Comment: Idiomatic Rust does not use redundant type annotations. All of the `: u32` inside the body of your function should be removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation for `cfg!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.cfg.html) states:

> Boolean evaluation of configuration flags.

That means that `cfg!(...)` is replaced with a Boolean (`true` / `false`). Your code would look something like this, after it's expanded:

```
fn test() -> u32 {
    let x = 3;
    if true {
        let y = 2;
        x + y
    }
    if true {
        let y = 1;
        x + y
    }
}
```

The easiest solution is to add an `else`:

```
fn test() -> u32 {
    let x = 3;
    if cfg!(feature = "complex") {
        let y = 2;
        x + y
    } else {
        let y = 1;
        x + y
    }
}
```

You can also use the attribute form of `cfg`. In this case, the attribute can prevent the entire next expression from being compiled:

```
fn test() -> u32 {
    let x: u32 = 3;

    #[cfg(feature = "complex")]
    {
        let y: u32 = 2;
        x + y
    }

    #[cfg(feature = "simple")]
    {
        let y: u32 = 1;
        x + y
    }
}
```

> as it tries to evaluate both expressions.

No, it doesn't. Evaluation occurs at run-time, and this code cannot even be compiled.

See also:

- [Is it possible to conditionally compile a code block inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24396293/155423)
- [Example of how to use Conditional Compilation Macros in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34777302/155423)
- [How many lines are covered by the Rust conditional compilation attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39291850/155423)

Comment: "Evaluation occurs at run-time, and this code cannot even be compiled." - Well, if the decision to put `false` or `true` under `cfg!(feature = "complex")` is done at compile time, so what prevents the compiler/optimizer to delete these branches at all (`if false` because it is unreachable and `if true` because it is meaningless). So, there will be no evaluation at runtime at all.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy you are mostly right — `if false` and `if true` *should* be removed at compile time, at least when optimizing. The body of `if false` should be removed, but the body if `if true` should be kept. Then whichever blocks are `true` will be evaluated at run time. This is another reason to use `else` — to prevent *both* feature's code blocks from being evaluated! Note also that this type of optimization should not change the behavior of the program.

Comment: @Shepmaster that was what I meant :)